# Spring @Value Returns Null On Class Implementation When @Configuration

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-annotations

I have a class which implements an interface. I want to inject some fields using springs @Value annotation. This works without issue on other parts of the project but not on this class. The class has the annotation of @Configuration which from research is whats meant to fix these kinds of issues and put it in the spring boot context. My code is

```
@Configuration
public class RedissonRegionFactory implements RegionFactory
{
    @Value("${spring.redis.host}")
    private String redisHost; // returns null
    @Value("${spring.redis.port}")
    private String redisPort; // returns null
```

I have used these variables elsewhere in the project and return without issue. They are stored in a application.properties file. Another thing is that @Autowire also does not work and is likely linked to the same issue. What change do I need to do to get it to wire correctly?

Comment: what methods do you override from this RegionFactory?

Comment: start, stop, isMinimalPutsEnabledByDefault, getDefaultAccessType, nextTimestamp, buildEntityRegion, buildNaturalIdRegion, buildCollectionRegion and buildTimestampsRegion

Comment: It would make more sense for `RedissonRegionFactory` to be a `@Component`, it seems

Answer (score 0):

Check the package that is specified for scan by Spring.
This can be a @ComponentScan annotation with a package other than the package that contains your RedissonRegionFactory.
Or is your class a level higher in the package than your *SpringApplication*.

Comment: It is already in a \@ComponentScan package. Its in the same folder as all of my other \@Configuration class' which all work and can use @Value without issue and autowire as expected